# Is there any consequences of using global/window variables in angular template itself?

Tags: javascript, angular, global

Is there any consequences of using global/window variables in angular template itself ?

**Example**

sample-template.ts

```
export class SampleComponent {
  console = console;
  myArr = Array;
  myObj = Object;
  data = [{name: 'abc', ...}, {myName: 'xyz', ...}, {fullName: 'pqr', ...}]
}
```

sample-template.html

```
<div>{{console.log('It logs')}}</div>

<div *ngFor="let each of Arr(4).fill(1);let i=index;">{{'I just need index here' + i}}</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of data">
 <div *ngFor="let col of myObj.keys(item)">{{col}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can't use global variables it have it's limitation

In terms of syntax, template expressions are similar to JavaScript. Many JavaScript expressions are legal template expressions, with a few exceptions.

**You can't use JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects, including:**

Assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
Operators such as new, typeof, instanceof, etc.
Chaining expressions with ; or ,
The increment and decrement operators ++ and --
Some of the ES2015+ operators

Comment: refer here for more info https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax